# What exactly causes the inaccuracy in a simple buffer setup

Tags: compressure

In the game Compressure, in Level 6, you need to create a buffer.

However, the setup described by Lady Chavvington in that level contains a small inaccuracy, as confirmed by Nicola at the start of the next level.

What exactly causes the inacuraccy in the setup described in that level?

(example of that inaccuracy pictured below)

[image: compressure simple buffer setup.]